# ODP.NET difference between OracleException.ErrorCode and OracleException.Number?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, odp.net

Going to convert an old VB.NET application from the depricated `System.Data.OracleClient` Microsoft provider to ODP.NET `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` (version 4.122.1.0) and am wondering if there is a difference between:

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException.ErrorCode` "Gets the HRESULT of the error"

vs.

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException.Number` "Specifies the Oracle error number"

The old code had references to `System.OracleClient.OracleException.Code` where the result would be 6550 when the error was "ORA-06550" (note: the result was not negative ex. -6550)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested this by throwing a unique constraint "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated"

The results were:

```
ex.ErrorCode = -2147467259

ex.Number = 1
```

I will therefore replace references to `System.OracleClient.OracleException.Code` with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException.Number`